# How to check the correctness of the message, depending on the language used on Android?

Tags: java, android, robotium

I check the text on the screen method by Robotium:

```
assertTrue(solo.waitForText("Wrong password"));
```

or

```
assertTrue(solo.searchText("Wrong password"));
```

However, my application can work in several languages​​, and at a time working with the language specified in Android as the language used. Application is written in Java. How to check the correctness of the message, depending on the language used on Android?

Comment: Can't you use `context.getResources().getString(R.string.wrongpass)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the string resources of the original project from the test project, so you can access to the ids of the original strings. If you would like support more languages than you should use localized string resources, here is the link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get localised String without changing your current configuration (API>=17):

```
Configuration config = new Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration()); 
config.setLocale(locale);   
return context.createConfigurationContext(config).getText(resId);
```

Where `locale` is one you want to test against.

If you're targeting lower API levels:

```
Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("de");
// Then update resources based on this Configuration. 
context.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
// Afterwards, resources will retrieve localised strings instead of default locale
String deLocaleString = context.getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);
```